# Reducing by (K,V) pairs and sort by V

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd, reduce

I'm super new to pyspark and RDDs. Apologies if this question is very rudimentary.

I have mapped and cleaned by data using the following code:

```
delay = datasplit.map(lambda x: ((x[33], x[8], x[9]))).filter(lambda x: x[0]!= u'0.00').filter(lambda x: x[0]!= '')
```

but now I need to somehow convert into the following output:

```
(124, u'"OO""N908SW"')
(432, u'"DL""N810NW"')
```

where the first is a sum of `x[33]` mentioned above when grouped by a combination of x[8] and x[9]

I've completed the mapping and get the below output (which is close)

```
lines = delay.map(lambda x: (float(x[0]), [x[1], x[2]]))
```

Output:

```
[(-10.0, [u'OO', u'N908SW']),(62, [u'DL', u'N810NW]), (-6.0, [u'WN', w'N7811F'])]
```

but I can't figure out how to reduce or combine `x[1]` and `x[2]` to create the output shown above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you want as little python operations as possible.

I reduced your code to one `map` and one `reduce`.

```
import operator

delay_sum = datasplit\
    .map(lambda x: (x[8]+x[9], float(x[33]) if any(x[33]) else 0.0))\
    .reduceByKey(operator.add)
```

And it goes without saying, that these kind of operations usually run faster when using spark dataframes.

Comment: It can be erroneous! as you assume `x[8] + x[9]` has a one-to-one map to pair of `(x[8], x[9])`, but it's not true generally.

Comment: This is what the OP requested. This is a solution for his specific case and assumptions, not for any general unspecified case.

Comment: The OP just provides a sample! Hence, this code just works for his sample and not more anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

You can create key likes below and the apply `reduceByKey` and then map to get unified key:

```
from operator import add
result = delay.map(lambda x: ((x[1], x[2]), x[0])) \
                  .reduceByKey(add).map(lambda x: (x[0][1] + x[0][2], x[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but I get an error message: IndexError: tuple index out of range